# Replace anything within two brackets

Tags: java, regex

I have this string:

```
String string = "The status is %status(" + randomString + ")%";
```

How can I replace the part between percent signs with anything, but without knowing randomString?

Comment: Where is your code? What doesn't work?

Comment: In your title you mentioned replacing text between brackets but in question between percent signs. So which is it? For current example it may not matter that much but we would like to avoid situation when you later give additional examples which will invalidate posted answers.

Comment: Can you have brackets inside brackets?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String.replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). An example:

```
String randomString = "asdf";
String string = "The status is %status(" + randomString + ")%";
String replacement = "myStatus";
String fString = string.replaceAll("%status(.*)%", replacement);
System.out.println(fString);
```

Which outputs:

```
The status is myStatus
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex you want to use is `%(.+)%`, which matches `%status(foo)%` and `%status(asidh37887123-48hsZXas;;fgfg)%`.

To replace it, you can do `string.replaceAll("%(.+)%", "anything")`.

This will turn `The status is %status(foo)%` to `The status is anything`.

Comment: Now I am interested what OP will want for text like `"foo %x(...)% bar %y(...)%"`. Or `"foo %x(%y(..)%..)%"`.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do it :

```
String string = "The status is %status(aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa)%";
        int x = string.indexOf("%");
        int y = string.lastIndexOf("%");
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(y);
        string = string.substring(0,x)+string.substring(y+1,string.length());
        System.out.println(string);

        string = "The status is %status(aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa)%";
        string = string.replaceAll("%.+%", "");
        System.out.println(string);
```

Result :

[image]